# Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred when adding to Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays:

```
var myDict : [String:[SomeObj]] = [:]
```

To populate it, I try to add a value to the array at the correct index. If the array does not exist, it fails and I make a new array at that index:

```
if myDict[key]?.append(val) == nil {
    myDict[key] = [val]
}
```

I think I should be able to shorten this to:

```
myDict[key]?.append(val) ?? myDict[key] = [val]
```

However, instead I get the error: `Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred`. Why?

Comment: You are using `nil-coalescing` for wrong purpose. Don't use them for ___whatever, it just works___ reason.

Comment: @nayem Can you elaborate? Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

***Consider the simple concept :-***

While using `if...else` in *single line* the operations should be single or else we need to mate operations under `parenthesis` to make it as a single operation, in our case `append(val)` is a single operation but  `myDict[key] = [val]` is multiple (`myDict[key]` is one and `=` assignment is one and `[val]` is one ) so we are *grouping them into single using `parenthesis`*.

At more simple way consider the following `arithmatic operations`.

```
//I need 10-5 = 5
let a = 2*4+2-4-3*5
print(a) // -9
//so we can seprate by ()
let b = ((2*4)+2)-(4-3)*5
print(b) //5
```

Here, we are instructing the compiler not a expected way at `let a`.

Also see,

```
let a:Int? = nil
var b:Int? = nil
let d = 10

let c = a ?? 10 * b ?? d
```

Here `let c` is wrong instruction, error is,

> Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?

If i force `unwrapping` the `optionals a and b`, then the error will become,

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So the constant `c` becomes,

```
let c = a ?? 10 * (b ?? d) //100
```

That's you should use `parenthesis` around the `default` value.

```
myDict[key]?.append(val) ?? (myDict[key] = [val])
```

Comment: Nice. Any idea what the error is trying to explain?

Comment: @GoldenJoe , see the explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

It's better to do this:

```
var array = myDict.removeValue(forKey: key) ?? []
array.append(item)
myDict[key] = array
```

It removes the `array` from `myDict` prior to mutation, so that `array` will be the only reference to the array's memory. Because it is uniquely referenced, mutable operations can be performed to it without having to copy the array's memory.

Without this, each `myDict[key]?.append(val)` call causes a copy-on-write operation.