# Can I use Optional chaining to give a default value for the property of an optional?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

Is it possible to use optional chaining and nil coalescing simultaneously like so?

```
print("Meeting host: " + meeting.host?.email ?? “No host”)
```

I'd like to do this but I get an error saying that my String? is not unwrapped. `email` is a non optional String.

Is this possible without having to unwrap `host` before hand and if not why does my attempt at doing this not work?

Comment: If you get an "unexpected" compiler error, divide the expression into smaller parts. In your case: Start with `let host = meeting.host?.email ?? "No host" ; print("Meeting host: " + host)` – You'll notice that that compiles, so the optional chaining and nil-coalescing  works generally.

Comment: See here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877393/6479530

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to unwrap it to get it to work. That is not why the error occurred. The `??` is designed to handle such cases, after all.

The error occurs because of operator precedence. The compiler thinks that it should evaluate the `+` first, concatenating the two strings, THEN do the nil-coalescing. It sees that the second operand is  not unwrapped and complains.

To make it produce the intended result, explicitly tell the compiler to evaluate the `??` first by adding brackets:

```
print("Meeting host: " + (meeting.host?.email ?? “No host”))
```

Comment: Note that using `+` this way can explode compile times. Strongly avoid `+` with strings; it's the #1 cause of "my Swift takes too long to compile" questions. One is fine, but even two or three lead to exponential problems. Get in the habit of string interpolation: `print("Meeting host: \(meeting.host?.email ?? "No host")")` This also happens to get rid of the precedence problem Sweeper explains so well.

Comment: print() takes a variable number of arguments, so one can also write `print("Meeting host:", meeting.host?.email ?? "No host")`

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier solution for this:

```
class Host {
    var email: String?
}

var host: Host? = nil
print("Meeting host: " + String(describing: host?.email))
```

The output is:

> Meeting host: nil

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing. `host` is an optional so `host.email` wouldn't compile.

Comment: But for a non-nil value this will display `Meeting host: Optional(Bob)` or something like that, right?